# Смещение колонок в OpenCart, Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, bootstrap, opencart

работаю в Opencart 3, Bootstrap 3. Сделал footer, но при разрешение sm(меньше 992) колонки смещаются и получается свободное пространство, что делаю не так?

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      {% if informations %}
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h5>{{ text_information }}</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
         {% for information in informations %}
          <li><a href="{{ information.href }}">{{ information.title }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h5>{{ text_service }}</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="{{ contact }}">{{ text_contact }}</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ return }}">{{ text_return }}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h5>{{ text_extra }}</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="{{ voucher }}">{{ text_voucher }}</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ affiliate }}">{{ text_affiliate }}</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ special }}">{{ text_special }}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <a href="tel:{{ telephone }}" class="phone" title="Нажми чтобы позвонить нам">{{ telephone }}</a>
    <a href="mail:{{ email_2 }}" class="email">{{ email_2 }}</a>
    <a href="lendik.me" class="powered">{{ text_powered }}</a>
    <div class="soc">
     <a href="http://lendik.me" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a>
     <a href="http://lendik.me" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
     <a href="http://lendik.me" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Колонки должны идти в такой порядке: Информация, Служба поддержки, Дополнительно. Но после службы поддержки появляется невидимая колонка.
Стилизация не как не влияет пробовал выключать css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в **row** обвёрнуты все **col-sm-6**. Таким образом, если в **row** у блоков разная высота и блоков больше чем на 12 колонок (а сейчас на 24), **bootstap** выстаивает их в соответствии с их индексом колонок но "гапит" под теми блоками, которые по высоте больше. Т.е. вы наблюдаете, как он компенсирует высоту смежных блоков с разной высотой.

Задайте этим блокам (тем что внутри данного row, первые потомки - col-sm-6) min-height равное высоте самого высокого из них.